# Exact Yalkut Shimoni Reference

Tags: sources-mekorot, midrash, zephaniah-book

So says the Gemara in Masechta Sanhedrin, 39a: “Caesar said to R' Tanchum, 'Come, let us all become one nation.' Rabbi Tanchum said: 'Very well. But we, who are circumcised, cannot become uncircumcised as you are; you all circumcise yourselves and become like us.'”

The Midrash, in Yalkut Shimoni and regarding Zeph. 3:9, quotes this same Caesar's challenge as follows: “Come, let us all become one nation in fulfillment of the verse, For then will I turn all the nations into a refined people who will all call upon the Name of G-d and serve Him as one. Since all the nations are anyway destined to worship together, let us start doing so now!”

I wanted to find out exactly on what daf the reference in Yalkut Shimoni referred to above can be found.  I understand that it must be somewhere within §§ 515-595 to the twelve minor prophets.  If you could possibly provide the exact location, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 5):

A quick search on Sefaria turned up a [piece of §567](https://www.sefaria.org/Yalkut_Shimoni_on_Nach.567.7):

> כי אז אהפוך אל עמים שפה ברורה לקרוא כלם בשם ה' לעבדו, אמר ליה קיסר לרבי תנחומא תא נהוי כלנו עמא חד דכתיב כי אז אהפוך וגו'. א"ל לחיי מיהו אנן דמהלינן לא מצינן דנהוי כוותייכו, אתון מהולו והוו כוותין, אמר ליה מימר שפיר קאמרת מיהו כל דזכי למלכא לישדיוה לביבר, שדיוה לביבר לא אכלוהו, א"ל ההוא אפיקורוס הא דלא אכלוהו משום דלא כפיין, שדיוה לדידה ואכלוהו. א"ר יוסי כי אז אהפוך אל עמים מלמד שכל האומות יהיו גרים גרורים לעתיד לבא, אמר ליה אביי ודילמא מע"א הוא דהדרי בהו, א"ל לעבדו שכם אחד כתיב, לשעבר כתיב הבה נרדה ונבלה שם שפתם וכתיב בלע ה' פלג לשונם, אבל לעתיד לבא אהפוך אל עמים שפה ברורה: